# The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

you see the controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController implements ErrorController {


    @RequestMapping("/v1")
    public String home()
    {
        return "index";
    }


     private static final String PATH = "/error";

        @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
        public String error() {
            return "Error handling kova";
        }

        @Override
        public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }
}//CLASS
```

I have added the following attribute into the file.

application.properties add

> server.port=8087

and the error output looks like this:
I am having problems changing my port number.

and **error** port problem

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:256) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) [spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.userfront.UserFront1Application.main(UserFront1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2018-05-26 23:19:10.439  INFO 1460 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-05-26 23:19:10.460  INFO 1460 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-26 23:19:10.468 ERROR 1460 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2018-05-26 23:19:10.470  INFO 1460 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1761df8: startup date [Sat May 26 23:19:05 EEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-26 23:19:10.473  INFO 1460 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: You can find the process using 8080- 
netstat -nlp | grep 8080

Then do a kill -9 <pid> or in Windows just go to the Task Manager and find the port

Comment: I do not know how to do it in windows system.
Could you help ?
how to close ports?

Comment: Let's show your console log after changing port to 8087!

Comment: try to do java -Dserver.port=8087 -jar name-of-file.jar

Comment: this should definitely try to start it on port 8087.

Comment: Should I write understood?
**server.port=8087 --> application.properties**  ?
ANOTHER ?

Comment: this **-Dserver.port=8087 -jar name-of-file.jar** what ?

Comment: run cmd as administrator In Windows to find the pid use 
netstat -anob | findstr 8080
Go to task manager under details find the pid and right click and end task. 

Otherwise the answer above is correct:
java -jar -Dserver.port=8087 spring-boot-example-1.0.jar
This will start a jar on that port.

Question: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Spring Tools IDE

Comment: STS has an embedded Tomcat instance that runs on 8080. Make sure the embedded Tomcat is not running.  You should see a red stop button in STS Eclipse. If you don't have Tomcat Installed its using the embedded Tomcat and you need to stop the service.

Comment: can u start ur application from the command prompt. Travel to the location where your jar is and run this command - 

java -Dserver.port=8087 -jar name-of-file.jar

Comment: If you're running the sun then you have to stop. and then run it from scratch.

Comment: ANSWER : 
**it should be stopped after compiling and running the project.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open Command Prompt and run `netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80` to find the UID using the port 8080.
Then open Task Manager, select Details, find the port showed in CMD and end task.

Comment: What can I do when I want to leave (or have to leave) process live? I have necessary service running on 8080.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [red icon to stop the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUn1z.png).

Just hit that and then hit the play or run icon. This will kill the port and start again